# Why show me the first option in my dropdown?

Tags: php, sql, database, select, pdo

I don't know what is the problem.

I have this part of my php:

```
public function fillObject(){

try {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123asd";
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bd_actividades", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pro_nombre FROM act_proyecto");
     $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();


    foreach ($result as $row) {
    $aObjects=array();
    $oTransfer = new TransferProyeCtr();

    $oTransfer->setNombre($row['pro_nombre']);

    $oTransfer->setState(1);
    $aObjects[]=$oTransfer;
    return $aObjects;
} }catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
} }
```

this send the results : `$oTransfer->setNombre($row['pro_nombre']);`

And in my dropdown show this:

[image]

But I need this :

[image]

What is the problem? 
Here is my module where I print:

Ajax:

```
llenarComboProyectos: function(iSecciones){

    var self = this;

    self.ajaxCall('http://localhost:8080/PROJECTS/dailytasks/api/sistemaTareas/v1/'+"proyectos","GET", null).then(function(data) {
        console.info("data",data);
        if(self.checkError(data[0].state)){
            self.llenarCombos(iSecciones,data);
        }else{
            alert("error service");
        }
    });
},
```

Where I print:

```
llenarCombos: function(secciones,data){

        var self = this;    
        console.info(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var cProyectos = "<option>"+data[i].nombre_proyecto+"</option>"; 
            for(var iCont=0;secciones>=iCont; iCont++){
                $("#select_proyecto_"+iCont+"_id").append(cProyectos);
                $("#select_proyecto_"+iCont+"_id").selectpicker('refresh');  
            }   
        }
},
```

here I get pro_nombre: `var cProyectos = "<option>"+data[i].nombre_proyecto+"</option>";`

Comment: You need to show the code that prints out the `select` options. (*Which I assume is this function: `$oTransfer->setNombre()`*)

Comment: dump your $results before the foreach loop, makesure the database has returned all your required records

        echo "<pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre>";

Comment: Yes @Darren sorry, I edit.

Comment: @JeanAndrésBergeretFuhrhop You need to show the code from `->setNombre()`, it's most likely coming from there.

Comment: I edit again @Darren

Comment: But the problem is before because there I get only "proyecto 1"

Comment: It's because you return data in `foreach` so it gets the first value only. Move  the `return` and `$aObjects[]=$oTransfer;` out of the loop.

Comment: I put $aObjects=array(); and  return $aObjects;
 out o the loop and work!  thank you @Thiêm and all

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

from your first script.
I think this will solve your problem.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php